# MSMQ: MessageQueue.Close() throws exception -1073741536 at .EndReceive()

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, msmq, message-queue

I'm using **MSMQ** inside a Windows Service.
When the service is paused, I'd like to **close MSMQ** and reopen it when the service is resumed.

The code looks like this:

**OnStart**

```
_mq.ReceiveCompleted += this.ReceiveCompletedHandler;
_mq.BeginReceive();
```

**OnPause**

```
// MessageQueue.ClearConnectionCache();
_mq.Close();
```

**OnContinue**

> same as OnStart

Now, this works BUT after `.Close()` an exception is thrown in the `ReceiveCompletedHandler`:

```
private void ReceiveCompletedHandler(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Message message = this.mq.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult); // or e.Message
    // do stuff
}
```

**Exception details:**

Type: `MessageQueueException`
Message: `null`
ErrorCode: `-2147467259`
MessageQueueErrorCode: `-1073741536`

How do I **prevent** this **from happening**?

Comment: It is a low-level Windows error code, ERROR_CANCELLED, "The I/O request was cancelled".  Well, it was, you jerked the floor mat by closing the queue while it still had a pending read.  

This is normally supposed to generate an ObjectDisposedException, you *must* wrap the EndReceive() call with try/catch so you can deal with that.  Smells like you have some non-standard network drivers or anti-malware getting in the way of generating a better exception.  You'd better catch this exception as well if you can't figure out what's special on that machine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's what I've done now, but I was hoping there was a way to prevent the exception, rather than catching it.

Comment: No, you *always* get an exception.  Something exceptional happened, you started a read but it couldn't be completed normally.  So it lets you know about that so you can cleanup state.  This is all entirely normal and catching the exception is expected.  The non-exceptional way is to stop calling BeginRead, not practical.

Comment: So be it :) Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't like that ERROR_CANCELLED error code.  It isn't normal and I can't give a good reason why you see it.

Answer (score 1):

David,

In your OnPause try do this before call Close() method:

_mq.ReceiveCompleted -= this.ReceiveCompletedHandler;